# Update Syntax error in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to update datebase with datagridview data here is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity= Quantity + " + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value + " where ItemName='" + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value + "'", mycon);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            x += 1;
        }
```

it gives syntax error near where.

Comment: your input are valid?

Comment: Show an example input for which this has been tested.

Comment: use params in query

Comment: Before you do anything else please read about CommandParameters, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements and https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @joeTaras my input is Text and ItemName is nvarchar(25)

Comment: Shudder. Please, please, please don't concatenate input into sql queries. That is just ripe for SQL Injection, which is a huge and genuine problem.

Comment: @Farhadpaikan Please open the SQL Profiler and check the query that is being executed by SQL Server. It might be that dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value has an invalid value

Answer (score 3):

2 things are wrong :

1. tdataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value might produce a value with a comma in it which is recognized by the database so a value of 10,4 is not seen as 10.4 but the 4 is seen as a new field
   OR
   some value you assign from your dataGridView is empty
2. Use parameters instead of building your query like this, not only is it safer but it will also fix your problem with the quantity field

example :

```
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity where ItemName = @ItemName";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Quantity, dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value);  
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@ItemName, dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

EDIT : the OP wants to increase the quantity field.

```
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity where ItemName = @ItemName";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Quantity, dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value);  
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@ItemName, dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And if the cell can be empty you can replace the empty with 0 like this so that you just add 0 to quantity instead of getting an exception.

```
cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity where ItemName = @ItemName";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Quantity, dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value ?? 0);  
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@ItemName, dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Syntax was quantity = quantity + datagridview cell , i want to increase to quantity field

Comment: I have put an edit in my answer how you can add to the quantity using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters, appending strings in SQL queries is a very bad idea (SQL-Injection). Below should make the error clearer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    decimal qty = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value);
    string itemName = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value;
    string commandText = "UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity= Quantity + @p1 WHERE ItemName = @p2";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(commandText, mycon);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", qty);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", itemName);

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the syntax error is coming from the SQL concatenation. If so, parameterization should fix it. You can use tools like [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) to make it trivial to parameterize correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string itemName = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value;
    // note: I don't know what the actual type is here; int? decimal?
    int quantity = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value;
    myCon.Execute(
        "UPDATE Pharmacy_Items Set Quantity=Quantity+@quantity where ItemName=@itemName",
        new { itemName, quantity });
    x += 1;
}
```